# How do you make a radial fading on top of a background image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, shading

I have three objects that I want to superimpose on each other: Some text upon a background picture using a circle to create a radial fading from white to transparent so that it is possible to read the text.

I'm not sure if it's because of my TeX engine (PdfLaTeX and LaTeX in sharelatex.com) but for some reason I cant get the circle to fade into transparency with the background image.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,trees,fadings} 



\pgfdeclareradialshading{myshading}{\pgfpointorigin}{%
color(0mm)=(white);
% color(5mm)=(pgftransparent!10);
% color(8mm)=(pgftransparent!20);
color(15mm)=(pgftransparent!100)
}

\pgfdeclarefading{myfading}{\pgfuseshading{myshading}}


\tikzset{
    >=stealth',
  punkt2/.style={
         rectangle,
         rounded corners,
         dashed,
         draw=black, thick,
         text width=7em,
         minimum height=2em,
         text centered},
    level 1/.style={sibling angle=45, level distance=3.5cm},
    edge from parent/.style= {draw=none},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[opacity=0.5] (img2) at (0,7.5) {\includegraphics[height=18cm]{greenelephant}};
\shade[shading=myshading] (0,7.5) circle (5.5);

\coordinate (main2) at (0,7.5) [counterclockwise from=90]
    child { node[punkt2, text width=10em, solid] (a1) {State 0}}
    child { node[punkt2] (a2) {State 1}}
    child { node[punkt2] (a3) {State 2}}
    child { node[punkt2] (a4) {State 3}}
    child { node[punkt2, text width=10em, solid] (a5) {State 4}}
    child { node[punkt2] (a6) {State 5}}
    child { node[punkt2] (a7) {State 6}}
    child { node[punkt2] (a8) {State 7}};


\draw[->] (a1) edge[bend right=10] (a2);
\draw[->] (a2) edge[bend right=10] (a3);
\draw[->] (a3) edge[bend right=10] (a4);
\draw[->] (a4) edge[bend right=10] (a5);
\draw[->] (a5) edge[bend right=10] (a6);
\draw[->] (a6) edge[bend right=10] (a7);
\draw[->] (a7) edge[bend right=10] (a8);
\draw[->] (a8) edge[bend right=10] (a1);

\node at (0,7.5) (label2) {\textsc{Cycle}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Instead of the command

```
\shade[shading=myshading] (0,7.5) circle (5.5);
```

I have also tried with this one

```
 \pgfsetfading{myfading}{} \fill[white] (0,7.5) circle (5);
```

but this command seems to interrupt the rest of the processing because then I dont get even the circle or the text.

[image]

Comment: Or conversely, if it was possible to draw a transparent hole in the green elephant, then that would also work.

Comment: Does it have to be really transparent? Or can you use white? Or some other background colour?

Comment: Please make sure your code compiles before uploading unless your question is about a compilation error. (In which case, make sure the code produces the error you're asking about.) This (obviously) won't compile ;).

Comment: In your picture, you use the shading you've created. But you don't use the fading, do you?

Comment: When I tried with the fading then it seemed to break the rendering of both the circle and the text for some reason on my machine.
(I've updated the code with the missing `\begin{tikzpicture}` so it's compilable again)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this? I am afraid I don't have an elephant, so I've substituted a tiger.

[image: somewhere at least near the eye of the tiger?]

Or (**EDIT**) like this?

[image: invert fading and hide the eye]

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,trees,fadings}
\pgfdeclareradialshading[radialcolour1,radialcolour2,radialcolour3]{myshading}{\pgfpointorigin}{%
  color(0)=(radialcolour1);
  color(15bp)=(radialcolour2);
  color(50bp)=(radialcolour3)
}
\tikzset{%
  radial inner colour/.code={
    \colorlet{radialcolour1}{#1}
  },
  radial mid colour/.code={
    \colorlet{radialcolour2}{#1}
  },
  radial outer colour/.code={
    \colorlet{radialcolour3}{#1}
  },
  radial inner colour=white,
  radial mid colour=white!50!black,
  radial outer colour=black,
  my inner shading/.style={
    radial inner colour=#1,
    shading=myshading,
  },
  my mid shading/.style={
    radial mid colour=#1,
    shading=myshading,
  },
  my outer shading/.style={
    radial outer colour=#1,
    shading=myshading,
  },
  >={Stealth[]},
  punkt2/.style={
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    dashed,
    draw=black,
    thick,
    text width=7em,
    minimum height=2em,
    text centered},
  level 1/.style={sibling angle=45, level distance=3.5cm},
  edge from parent/.style={draw=none},
}
\tikzfading[name=myfading, my inner shading=transparent!100, my outer shading=transparent!0, my mid shading=transparent!0]
\tikzfading[name=myfading2, my inner shading=transparent!0, my mid shading=transparent!25, my outer shading=transparent!100]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [opacity=0.5] (img2) at (0,7.5) {\includegraphics[height=18cm]{tiger}};
  \fill [path fading=myfading, fill=white] (0,7.5) circle (5.5);
  \coordinate (main2) at (0,7.5) [counterclockwise from=90]
  child { node[punkt2, text width=10em, solid] (a1) {State 0}}
  child { node[punkt2] (a2) {State 1}}
  child { node[punkt2] (a3) {State 2}}
  child { node[punkt2] (a4) {State 3}}
  child { node[punkt2, text width=10em, solid] (a5) {State 4}}
  child { node[punkt2] (a6) {State 5}}
  child { node[punkt2] (a7) {State 6}}
  child { node[punkt2] (a8) {State 7}};
  \draw[->] (a1) edge[bend right=10] (a2);
  \draw[->] (a2) edge[bend right=10] (a3);
  \draw[->] (a3) edge[bend right=10] (a4);
  \draw[->] (a4) edge[bend right=10] (a5);
  \draw[->] (a5) edge[bend right=10] (a6);
  \draw[->] (a6) edge[bend right=10] (a7);
  \draw[->] (a7) edge[bend right=10] (a8);
  \draw[->] (a8) edge[bend right=10] (a1);
  \node at (0,7.5) (label2) {\textsc{Cycle}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [opacity=0.5] (img2) at (0,7.5) {\includegraphics[height=18cm]{tiger}};
  \fill [path fading=myfading2, fill=white] (0,7.5) circle (5.5);
  \coordinate (main2) at (0,7.5) [counterclockwise from=90]
  child { node[punkt2, text width=10em, solid] (a1) {State 0}}
  child { node[punkt2] (a2) {State 1}}
  child { node[punkt2] (a3) {State 2}}
  child { node[punkt2] (a4) {State 3}}
  child { node[punkt2, text width=10em, solid] (a5) {State 4}}
  child { node[punkt2] (a6) {State 5}}
  child { node[punkt2] (a7) {State 6}}
  child { node[punkt2] (a8) {State 7}};
  \draw[->] (a1) edge[bend right=10] (a2);
  \draw[->] (a2) edge[bend right=10] (a3);
  \draw[->] (a3) edge[bend right=10] (a4);
  \draw[->] (a4) edge[bend right=10] (a5);
  \draw[->] (a5) edge[bend right=10] (a6);
  \draw[->] (a6) edge[bend right=10] (a7);
  \draw[->] (a7) edge[bend right=10] (a8);
  \draw[->] (a8) edge[bend right=10] (a1);
  \node at (0,7.5) (label2) {\textsc{Cycle}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Close, but I was looking for the reverse. Where it fades out to transparent in the outer part of the circle and is white in the center. I'll try experiment with your code, thanks

Comment: Ok, I modified your code to get it how I wanted. This is more like it :) http://imgur.com/PPi5Tl1

I modified the following: `\tikzfading[name=myfading, my inner shading=transparent!0, my outer shading=transparent!100]` and added a `color(20bp)=(radialcolour1);` and a `color(25bp)=(radialcolour2);`

Comment: @PaulH Glad you sorted it. I figured this was probably not exactly what you wanted. I meant it more by way of an example of how to structure things, assuming you'd then adjust the details. (I happened to have code around from a shading question which I adapted slightly here.)

Comment: @PaulH I've tweaked slightly and decided to show how to do the fading either way on the basis of a single shading. Glad something here was helpful, anyhow!